# change dynamicaly the attribute value to make changes in color picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to change dynamicaly the  attribute value to make changes in color picker on:

```
<input id="uno" type="minicolors" name="123"   data-slider="wheel" />
```

theese are equivalent

```
$("#uno").val(str[1]);
$("#uno").value(str[1]);
$('input[name="123"]').val(str[1]);
$('input[name="123"]').attr('value',str[1]);
$('input[name="123"]').attr('input',str[1]);
$('INPUT[type=minicolors]').attr('value',str[1]);
```

the value is shown in text area but it doesn't change the slider on the color picker!

I tried this but doesn't work!

```
// $('input[name="123"]').attr('rgbObject',str[1]);  // no
// $('input[name="123"]').attr('rgbString',str[1]);  //no
// $.minicolors.rgbString(str[1]); //no
```

this is for test variable => do the job

```
$('input[name=123]').css("background", str[1]); // <==background text area color for testing
```

which attribute I have to work?

thanks

Comment: what is str[1] in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can see how it works: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-miniColors/

You have to use

```
$.minicolors.refresh()
```

once you have changed the text value to refresh the color picker.